# How To Filter The Data sent To The View According to the user login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This Is My Code

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Supplier")]
    public ActionResult Orders()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["error"] as string))
            ViewBag.Error = TempData["error"] as string;
        TempData.Clear();

   if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))//when the user logs in as the admin
        {
            var orders = _uow.orderRepo.GetAll().ToList();
            List<Models.Admin.OrderGridModel> model = null;
            model = (from c in orders 
                     select new Models.Admin.OrderGridModel()
                     {
                         OrderNumber = c.OrderNumber,
                         Date = c.Date,
                         Id = c.Id,
                         FullName = c.Person.FirstName + " " + c.Person.LastName,
                         PhoneNr = c.Person.Tel,
                         Email = c.Person.Email,
                         Price = BLL.PriceFormatter.FormatPrice(c.Price, c.Currency),
                         IsPaid = c.Zaplaceno,
                         Activities = (from a in c.OrderActivities
                                       select new Models.Admin.OrderGridActivityModel()
                                       {

                                           Id = a.Id,
                                           Time = a.Time,
                                           Name = a.Activity.Name,
                                           Date = a.Date,
                                           Status = a.Status,
                                           Supplier = a.Activity.Supplier != null ? a.Activity.Supplier.Name : "",
                                           BookingRefNr = a.SupplierRefNr,
                                           Hotel = c.Hotelname,
                                           Price = BLL.PriceFormatter.FormatPrice(a.Price, a.Order.Currency),
                                           PriceTypes = BLL.PriceFormatter.GetPriceTypesToString(a.OrderPrices),
                                           voucher_ext = a.VoucherFileExtension,
                                           voucher_name = a.VoucherFileName,
                                           voucher_type = a.VoucherFileContentype,

                                       }).ToList()
                     }).ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
        if (User.IsInRole("Supplier"))// when the user logs in as the supplier
        {
            //code for filtering according to the supplier 

        }

        return View();

    }
```

I am getting the orders from the database but i want it to be filtered when the supplier logs in only those records can will be returned in which the supplier name is according to the login

Comment: Supplier Name is the same as the username of the logged in user ?

Answer (score 0):

In your repository, you have this

```
_uow.orderRepo.GetAll();
```

Create another one where you filter by supplier id

```
public IList<Order> GetSupplier(string id)
{
    return context.Orders.Where(o => o.User.Id = id).ToList();
}
```

and then you can do this:

```
_uow.orderRepo.GetSupplier(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Where User.Identity.GetUserId() is the logged in user.